# difference between war file deployment on localhost and remote server (Tomcat)

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-mvc, deployment

I have a Spring MVC war file built with maven.
I copy it under the webapps directory in Tomcat on **localhost** and it works perfectly.

I have another tomcat running on a **remote server**. I copy the very same war file and it gives me 404! Why?

The versions of the to Tomcats are slightly different, but I don't think that could explain it.
Anyway here is the version of the one on localhost:

`Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Server built:   May 19 2014 10:26:15
Server number:  7.0.54.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.11.10-11-desktop
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_51-b00
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation`

Version of the one on remote server:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
Server built:   Mar 25 2014 06:20:16
Server number: 7.0.53.0
OS Name: NetBSD
OS Version:     6.1_STABLE
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0-internal-pkgsrc_2014_05_11_23_31-b00
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

So basically I have no idea what can cause this difference. In addition of copying the war file under webapps/ folder do I have to configure conf/server.xml?

UPDATE:
Here is the warning I get on remote server:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHelloWorld/WEB-INF/pages/helloWorld.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

**UPDATE** Here is the dispatcher servlet.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.srccodes.spring.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
  </beans>
```

Comment: Its a path mapping problem, as you can see in the error message. You cannot access files within /WEB-INF/ from a url. This directory can only be access from you application.

Comment: So how can I make those files accessible? What should I change on the deployed war to make those files accessible?

Comment: The question has been updated with the content of the dispatcher-servlet.The strange thing  is that it does work on my localhost-tomcat! It fails only on remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add the following fragments to WEB-INF/web.xml. Because these values were commented out on the remote server conf/web.xml file...

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>fork</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
```

and also this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the JSPs in a directory above WEB-INF, i.e. /SpringMVCHelloWorld/pages/helloWorld.jsp, or use a MVC framework to handle that internally. Spring MVC is a good place to start.

Comment: "or use a MVC framework to handle that internally. Spring MVC is a good place to start." That IS already a Spring MVC project. (Built with Maven)

Comment: Ok, please post the spring xyz-servlet.xml.